# Unity RotateAround() in combination with a specific direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

I'm trying to rotate my camera around a character, with a certain direction it needs to face. For example, I want my camera to rotate around my character, and stop the rotation when it faces another objects forward axis.
So I figured I needed a combination between RotateAround() and LookRotation().
RotateAround() to rotate the camera around the character, and LookRotation() to make the camera face that object aswell.

The problem is: I don't want my camera to move or rotate away from my character.

I tried a couple of things, the most thought out being this:

```
private void RotateCamera()
{
    Quaternion currentCameraRotation = _camera.transform.rotation;
    Quaternion futureCameraRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(_hitObstacleStartingPoint.transform.forward);
    float rotationAngle;
    Vector3 rotationAxis;
    Quaternion.FromToRotation(currentCameraRotation.eulerAngles, futureCameraRotation.eulerAngles).ToAngleAxis(out rotationAngle, out rotationAxis);
    _camera.transform.RotateAround(_character.transform.position, _camera.transform.up, rotationAngle);
}
```

But that ended up in my camera rotating all over the place..

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm sorry for my terrible explanation.
Here's a little drawing.
[image]

Comment: I think this needs a little clarity.  You "_don't want [your] camera to move or rotate away from [your] character_" and you also want to make the camera face the other object as well.  Do you mean you want both objects in view but the character should always be directly centered?  You also start by saying "_I want my camera to rotate around my character, and stop the rotation when it faces another objects forward axis._" which sounds like a slightly different situation.  Could you possibly draw a diagram or make some screenshots that better identify the specifics of what you want?

Comment: @Foggzie Sorry for the inconvenience, I added a picture to better explain what I mean.

Comment: You likely need to scale your rotation angle by Time.deltaTime

Comment: @MichaelG I tried, and it does rotate, but then it doesn't stop rotating once the camera is alligned with the object forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using fixed camera points in my scene. It avoids the problem, so I don't consider this one solved, but I have a deadline on this project and I can't afford to spend too much time on this problem anymore. Thanks to those of you who have helped me.

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate the distance between the current rotation angle, and the target rotation angle, and you can rotate around the pivot over time.

**See below:**

```
private void RotateCamera()
{
    Quaternion currentCameraRotation = _camera.transform.rotation;
    Quaternion futureCameraRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(obstacleObject.transform.forward, obstacleObject.transform.up);

    float angleDelta = Quaternion.Angle(currentCameraRotation, futureCameraRotation);

    _camera.transform.RotateAround(this._character.transform.position, _camera.transform.up, angleDelta * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);        
}
```

To help visualize what's going on:

```
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.green;
    Gizmos.DrawLine(_camera.transform.position, _camera.transform.forward * 20 + _camera.transform.position);

    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawLine(obstacleObject.transform.position, obstacleObject.transform.forward * 20 + obstacleObject.transform.position);
}
```

This doesn't work if your obstacle is rotated around x,z; it's always assuming a identity forward vector.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, I really appreciate it.
I've decided to just use fixed camera points to avoid the problem (see answer below)